# Sqlalchemy mysql parameterized query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pass table name as variable into a sql query and execute it with a sqlalchemy cursor:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

cur = DB_ENGINE.connect()
p = cur.execute(text('select * from :table'), {'table':'person'}).fetchall()
print p
```

and I got this error message:

```
ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''person'' at line 1") [SQL: u'select * from %s'] [parameters: ('person',)]
```

where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders can only represent VALUES. You cannot use them for sql keywords/identifiers.

If you need to dynamically change an identifier, then you'll have to build the query string yourself, e.g.

```
sql = "SELECT foo FROM " + var_with_table_name + "WHERE somefield = ?"
```

which then leaves you open to SQL injection attacks to boot.